# How To Fix Stack Corruptions Caused By Generating Random Enumeration Values?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, stack, runtime-error

I am making a CCG (Collective Card Game) using Win32 API but I ran into an error.

I created an enumeration with the names of different cards from *Hearthstone* (A Popular CCG) for testing purposes.

```
enum cardnames {ArcaneExplosion, ArcaneIntellect, ArcaneMissiles};
```

Then I created a array of enumeration objects called "Player Cards" (3 of them).

```
cardnames playercards[2];
```

I then set the objects to a random enumeration using the rand() function.

```
playercards[0] = cardnames(rand() % 2 + 0);
playercards[1] = cardnames(rand() % 2 + 0);
playercards[2] = cardnames(rand() % 2 + 0);
```

Then finally printing the enumeration to the console window.

```
cout << playercards[0] << endl;
cout << playercards[1] << endl;
cout << playercards[2] << endl;
```

But, this caused a stack corruption error and I am not very knowledgeable about how memory works. Can someone please help me fix this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is one value too small.  You declared:

```
cardnames playercards[2];
```

But then you write to `playercards[2]` later:

```
playercards[2] = cardnames(rand() % 2 + 0);
```

This will have undefined behaviour, as you are writing to stack memory immediately *after* the array.  Who knows what data was trashed?

Remember that the largest index you can use is *one less* than the array size.

Comment: Great Thank You! I Had Never Know That, I Will Mark This As The Answer Shortly.

Comment: Wow, you appear to enjoy capitalising words...  Anyway, no worries.  I should also point out that when you take `rand() % 2` it will return a value of either 0 or 1.  I think in this case you want `rand() % 3`.

Comment: tHANKs fOr aLl yOUr hELp. i wILl gEt my cAPITALISATIOn hABIt uNDEr cONTROl.